# How can I run this code and how can I improve this code?

Tags: python

```
import sys as s
import datetime


class LoginPage:

    def __int__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.incorrectPass = 0

    def loginProgrma(self):

        while True:
            while True:
                nameInput = input("Enter your username: ➸")
                if nameInput != self.username:
                    print("\t(Username is incorrect. Re-enter your username)")
                elif nameInput == self.username:
                    print("\t(Enter your password)")
                    break
            while True:
                passInput = input("Enter your password: ➳")
                if passInput != self.password:
                    self.incorrectPass += 1
                    print("\t(Incorrect password. Re-enter your password)")
                    if self.incorrectPass == 3:
                        s.exit('\nYou have been locked!')
                elif passInput == self.password:
                    break
            time = datetime.datetime.now()
            print('You logged in', time)

            return f"\n\t(Welcome back {nameInput}.)"
```

So I'm trying to make a short login program where where the program ask to enter the username and password. The problem I don't know how can I run this code, I tried by calling the class LoginPage and the pass 2 arguments(username, password) which is mot working I tried to find the solution on the internet but I couldn't find.

And how can I improve this code?.

Answer (score 1):

You have typed `__int__` instead of `__init__`. (You forgot an extra i) If you fixed that, you can after you called the class LoginPage call the loginProgrma function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the typo in `__init__` from `__int__` to `__init__`

Anyway there seem to be some typos in your code but to run the method you showed create an instance of the class and call the function like this:

```
#create instance
login_page =  LoginPage(username='username', password='password')

#call method 
login_page.loginProgrma()`
```

This should probably work